# Using validateAll() with custom v-select tag in scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vee-validate, v-select

I have a scenario where I have scoped a form so that I can validate it using [Vee-Validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/) using below method.

```
        validateTRForm: function (scope) {
        this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then((result) => {
            if (result) { }
```

[Vue Select Component](http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/) "scope" property is always null even if i added it in a form. However, it is working fine out of the scope.

My HTML && js file is some think like

```js
var selectComponent = Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    selected:'',
},
methods: {
    validateTRForm: function (scope) {
        this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    },
},
components: {
    component: selectComponent
}
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <form data-vv-scope="Test">
        <input name="textTest" v-validate="'required|email'" />
        <span v-show="errors.has('Test.textTest')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('Test.textTest') }}</span>      
        <v-select v-model="selected" data-vv-name="testVselect" v-validate="'required'" :options="[{label: 'Test1', value: '1'}, {label: 'Test2', value: '2'}, {label: 'Test3', value: '3'}]"></v-select>
        <span v-show="errors.has('Test.testVselect')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('Test.testVselect') }}</span>
        <button v-on:click.prevent="validateTRForm('Test')">Validate Elements</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `data-vv-scope="Test"` to the component.